# The template can't render images and blocks

Tags: magento2, template, media-images

In the frontend, the images URLs and blocks are not rendered. only show strings like this, and I don't know how to modify a template to render that.

> {{media url="wysiwyg/1S-Shine-2.png"}}

Comment: are you which magento  version ?

Comment: Are you using this in template files or cms pages?

Comment: This is in cms pages, magento 2

Answer (score 0):

The following is used to render images in Cms pages and blocks.

```
{{media url="wysiwyg/1S-Shine-2.png"}}
```

If you want to include an image in your template file use the following function in the corresponding block of your template file:

In your template Block file create __construct function.

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}


public function getMediaBaseUrl() {
    $mediaUrl = $this ->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    return $mediaUrl
}
```

And use this function in your template like below:

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getMediaBaseUrl() ?>wysiwyg/1S-Shine-2.png">
```